# Drawing in React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, drawing, draw

is it possible to do a drawing line and image in React native (like canvas in Android) and make a view like below?
[image]

Thanks in advance, any response is appreciated

Comment: Look at react-native-svg : https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg